# Subtract date and time from two NOWs

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, subtraction

I am trying to create a VBA code that calculates elapsed time after a certain action checkbox is clicked.

1. On clicking checkbox1 NOW is captured and display in textbox1.
2. on clicking checkbox2, NOW is displayed in textbox3 and the elapsed time (value in textbox3 - value in textbox1) needs to be displayed in textbox4 in hours and minutes format accurately. Which I am unable to do after trying and Googling for different codes.

I have remained on and off with VBA, so I am not fluent. Can someone help me with the piece of code?

---

```
Dim X1 As Date


Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

X1 = Now

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then TextBox1.Value = Now
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then TextBox1.Value = Null

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then TextBox2.Value = "00:00"
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then TextBox2.Value = Null


End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()

Dim X2 As Date
Dim X3 As Date
Dim X4 As Date

X2 = Now

If CheckBox2.Value = True Then TextBox3.Value = Now
If CheckBox2.Value = False Then TextBox3.Value = Null
If CheckBox2.Value = False Then TextBox4.Value = Null


X3 = X2 - X1
TextBox4.Value = X3

End Sub
```

Comment: Using the above code, is it possible to create a condition checkbox loop, lets say if checkbox1 is True, then taking the date/time from NOW (+ 50 minutes n repeat), i want a message popup "XYZ" with ok acknowledgement, and repeat every 50 minutes untill checkbox1 is False. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format the x3 value
```

change the last code line as below

```
TextBox4.Value = Format(X3, "hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Cool! That worked. Thanks a lot Dinesh. Taking the Now value is there a way to create a message popup every 50 minutes, with 'Ok' as the acknowledgement. i.e having it to create a popup message based on the condition of the checkbox. Let me know if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not solving your main query which seems to be about formatting but you should use multi line blocks in IF and use Else instead of another if!

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
X1 = Now
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then 
    TextBox1.Value = Now
     ' i dont think u need the following here but put here to show multi line if
     ' keepa  button to reset both text boxes
    TextBox2.Value = "00:00" 
elseif
     TextBox1.Value = Null
end if
 'keep in reset button click
'If CheckBox1.Value = False Then TextBox2.Value = Null
End Sub
```

REF http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

Comment: Thanks tgkprog for the simplified form :)

Comment: Why is this an Elseif as opposed to an Else? It can only be True or false